# Minmax value of sums of three consecutive terms in cyclic permutation.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Consider a permutation $(x_i)_{i=1,2,\dots,12}$ of the numbers $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. We
want to think of these as a cyclic permutation one way of doing this is to extend $x_i$ for every $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ as expected. For example $x_0 = x_n$ and so on.

Now let us define $a_i = x_{i-1} + x_i + x_{i+1}$, and let us ask the following question
¿If we set the permutation $x$ at "random", what is the lowest possible value of $\max\{a_i : i=1,2\dots,n\}$ we could get? Let us call this minmax value $t(n)$.

Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 3\sum_{i=1}^n = 3\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, and thus by a simple pigenhole
argument we know there must be some $i$ such that $a_i \geq \lceil \frac{1}{n}3\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\rceil = \lceil\frac{3}{2}(n+1)\rceil$. This gives the following lower bound:

$$\bigg\lceil\frac{3}{2}(n+1)\bigg\rceil \leq t(n)$$

By computing some values we see that $t(n)$ does frequently exceed the lower bound, but not always. Some values are given below in the form of $(n,t(n) - \lceil\frac{3}{2}(n+1)\rceil)$:
$$(3,0),(4,1),(5,1),(6,0),(7,2),(8,1),(9,1),(10,1),(11,2),(12,1)$$

Does anyone know a closed formula of $t(n)$? Or how it relates to this lower bound
asymptotically, that is, does this limit exist: $\lim_{n\to\infty} t(n) - \lceil\frac{3}{2}(n+1)\rceil$? if not, does it go to infinity?, etc. Anything among these lines really.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at OEIS (which I don't know why I didn't before) and it turns out that $t(n)$ is the sequence [A066385](https://oeis.org/A066385). There they cite some results by [Jon E. Schoenfield](https://oeis.org/wiki/User:Jon_E._Schoenfield), which I proceed to state here for completeness. First, let's define $f(n) := \lceil \frac{3}{2}n\rceil + 3$, then

- $t(n) = f(n)$ for all even $n > 6$.
- $f(n) -1 \leq t(n) \leq f(n)$ for all odd $n > 3$

And is a conjecture that $f(n) = t(n)$ for all $n>15$, which it is known
to hold (by computing $t(n)$) for all $15 < n \leq 38$.

Conclusion: it seems that as of now (June 2021) both questions are open.